# HTML / CSS Fullscreen layout width 3 columns

Tags: html, css, layout, fullscreen

I'm stuck with a problem. How to make full screen layout, where left and right columns are fixed width (for example 250px), but middle column is fluid. My page must be always be full screen!
I want something like this:

[image: screen layout]

Comment: Code please. We can't help you if we don't know what you've tried.

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not a place for people to come and get code written for them, but rather a place to troubleshoot code you've already tried yourself... Either way, take a look at this site, it might be able to get you what you want: http://csscreator.com/version2/pagelayout.php

Comment: Simplest solution http://jsfiddle.net/4jr8Y/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using a bit simple logic of CSS.

You have to create 3 different styles which can take care of Left content, middle content and right content. Here you go :

```
#fixed_width {
width:96px;
padding:2px;
border:1px solid #000;
float:left;
background-color:#f00;
}

#fixed_width_right {
width:96px;
padding:2px;
border:1px solid #000;
float:right;
background-color:#f00;
}

#unfixed_width {
padding:2px;
margin-left:105px;
border:1px solid #000;
background-color:#090; 
}
```

Use this CSS styles in your HTML code like below :

```
<div id="container">
<div id="fixed_width">col 1, 80 pixels </div>
<div id="fixed_width_right">col 3, 80 pixels </div>``
<div id="unfixed_width">col 2, wild card </div>
</div>
```

And you are done :)

Cheers..!!

Comment: Thanks.
I made it a little bit different, I used CSS calc() function.
E. g. width: calc(100% - 250px);
Too bad many old browsers doesn't support it.